# Set 24-hour time format for TimePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, material-design-in-xaml

I'm building an MVVM Light WPF app in Visual Studio 2015 using the [Material Design in XAML Toolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit). Here's the `TimePicker` control:

```
<materialDesign:TimePicker Is24Hours="True" />
```

Here's what the control looks like when you click it:

[image: TimePicker open]

Note that it shows the time in 24-hour format correctly. However, when you select that time and return to the field, it displays it as non-24-hour time, with AM/PM:

[image: TimePicker closed]

Is there any way to force the control to display the time in 24-hour format? Thanks.

Comment: What library is `TimePicker`? Is it built-in .NET 4.5?

Comment: It's this library: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Comment: **Fixed in [Version 2.5.0.1205](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialDesignThemes/2.5.0.1205).**    See [Issue 372](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/372) and [this pull request](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/pull/968).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 1.5 you can't explicitly enforce it:

You can use SelectedTimeFormat (long/short) e.g.

```
<materialDesign:TimePicker Is24Hours="True" SelectedTimeFormat="Long" />
```

**But**, this picks up the Windows regional setting short/long formats, so it depends on the local PC.

I guess I can add an override for a future release...