# Set AM/PM in Material Time Picker WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I'm building a simple WPF app in VS 15 .NET 4.5 and in need of Time Picker.
i used Material Design

```
<materialDesign:TimePicker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Is24Hours="False" x:Name="tPicker" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0 0 0 10" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Pick Time"  />
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1O91.jpg)

i'm getting only the time. there were no AM/PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show AM/PM next to the time, you will either have to change your computer's regional settings in the Control Panel:

[image]

Or you could set the `CurrentCulture` of the UI thread:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I am afraid you can't specify a custom format besides `Long` and `Short`:

[Set 24-hour time format for TimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141002/set-24-hour-time-format-for-timepicker)

Comment: i'm just signed up.i wasn't more concerned about the rules.thanks anyways.